# Find First cell With Data

Tags: excel, vba, do-while, is-empty

I am using the following in a macro to find the first cell with data in a row, and to move the cursor to that cell.

```vb
Do While IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

I would like it to be more efficient. This code scrolls down and takes a little to much time.

Comment: `Range("A" & application.match("*",Range("A:A"),0)).select`

Answer (score 0):

I would use `xlDown` for it. Would work in the other direction (`xlUp`) and for columns (`xlLeft`, `xlRight`), too:

```
Sub JumpToNextNotEmptyCellBelow()
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select  
End Sub
```

Comment: XlDown was perfect! Thanks.